# jQuery URL split and grab

Tags: jquery, url, split

So I have a URL and I know how to get $_GET from URL however my URL is `http://www.example.com/#!/edit/2695`.

Is there away to grab the url and spit the parts after `#!/`? I want edit and the ID.

Comment: Do you need `php` or JavaScript` solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var edit = window.location.hash.split('/')[1],
      ID = window.location.hash.split('/')[2];
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use this code

```
var url = "http://www.mysite.com/#!/edit/2695";
var pieces = url.split("/#!/");
pieces = pieces[1].split("/");

// pieces[0] == "edit"
// pieces[1] == "2695"
```

If you just wanted the number after the edit, you could also use a regex

```
var url = "http://www.mysite.com/#!/edit/2695";
var match = url.match(/#!\/edit\/(\d+)/);
if (match) {
    // match[1] == "2695"
}
```

You can see both of them work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4BTyH/