# jQuery: how to get URL and modify it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a link:

```
http://blog.isvn.pl/search/music
```

How can I modify this link with jQuery to get:

```
http://blog.isvn.pl/tagged/music
```

I want change only „search“ to „tagged“, and open new link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery URL split and grab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491721/jquery-url-split-and-grab)

Comment: `var url = ("http://blog.isvn.pl/search/music").replace("search", "tagged");` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**replace()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var url = 'http://blog.isvn.pl/search/music';
var newUrl = url.replace('/search/', '/tagged/');
window.location.href = newUrl;
//or, to open in a new window:
window.open(url,'_blank');
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h8KRQ/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), to replace *search* with *tagged*

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R5GaC/)**

```
url = url.replace('search', 'tagged');
```

To change the url

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('search', 'tagged');
```

OR

```
window.location.href = document.URL.replace('search', 'tagged');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var value = 'http://blog.isvn.pl/search/music'; 
value = value.replace("search", "tagged"); 
alert(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

use the replace function in javascript:

```
var currentUrl = "http://blog.isvn.pl/search/music";
var replacedUrl = currentUrl.replace("/search/", "/tagged/");
```

I use `/search/` (with the slashes) so it only replaces when it is a folder in the path. Otherwise it would also replace when the word search in in a song title.